# OnClickListener inside a for loop

Tags: android, for-loop, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm getting a "Error:(99, 95) error: local variable i is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final" for trying to use the "i" variable from a For loop in the OnClick method.
I tried to put this "i" inside a global variable but then I get a "ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException".
 But I can't think in another way to do so.

```
    private void createTextViews(TextView[] textViewArray, LinearLayout linearLayout){
    for (int i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        layoutParams.setMargins(20, 0, 0, 20);

        TextView newView = new TextView(getActivity());
        newView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        newView.setText("Watch the Trailer " + (i + 1));
        newView.setTextSize(22);
        newView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.words));
        newView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.button));
        newView.setHighlightColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.background));
        newView.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        newView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(YOUTUBE_URL+keys[i]));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        linearLayout.addView(newView);
        textViewArray[i] = newView;
    }
}
```

How can I do this?

--------------
EDIT
Here's the log for the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsExeption:

```
11-03 01:08:13.866  32159-32159/app.com.example.android.popularmovies E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: app.com.example.android.popularmovies, PID: 32159
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=3; index=3
        at app.com.example.android.popularmovies.Detail_ActivityFragment$1.onClick(Detail_ActivityFragment.java:99)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4456)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18465)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: where are you getting the error exactly on what line ?

Comment: The first parameter of the function has problem. Show from where and what you are sending to this function

Comment: @NJay Here: Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(YOUTUBE_URL+keys[i])); It says exactly "Error:(99, 95) error: local variable i is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final"

Comment: Please paste your error log here.

Comment: well a very simple way to solve it is to declare i as a class variable  @Cas

Comment: @NJay That's when I get the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: Please try pasting your whole activity code, as with this amount of code we cannot predict what causes the error..

Comment: @FireSun Just pasted.

Comment: your keys array is the problem I guess. Inside your `onClick()` you are trying to access that index of your array `keys[]` which does not exist. Hence you are getting the error.

Comment: @Cas check below answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must init new final int value

add `final int ex = i;`

before setOnClickListener

and don't forget to change

```
Uri.parse(YOUTUBE_URL + keys[i]));
```

to

```
Uri.parse(YOUTUBE_URL + keys[ex]));
```

Comment: @Cas glad to help you

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting the out of bound exception is because in the last loop you are i++ing although it is not entering the loop again but the i that is a class variable is now out of bound. So the whole approach of putting i as a class variable will not work in your case.

A way to achieve this is to actually save i in a tag in the view and then read that tag from the view that is clicked.

```
newView.setTag(i)
```

Then in the onClick

```
v.getTag()
```

above can be used to get the i

Comment: @Cas check solution that will solve ur problem. 
Make sure i is not a class variable anymore.